# Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, firebase-authentication

Getting error while using *Add Firebase Authentication to your App* in the Firebase authentication (Assistant).

The error shows in the Sync tab as:

> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
>   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

My Android Studio Details are:

- Android Studio version 3.2.1
- Gradle version: 4.6

---

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nsc.suyog.myotp1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the your build.gradle files (project and app) ?

Comment: Yes. what is the reason for this error?

Comment: have you try to update all versions like:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Comment: How to update them?

Comment: your firebase auth version is strange no ? Try the latest one `16.1.0`.

Comment: Above firebase version which i have posted is automatically added by studio. Updating from 16.0.x to 16.1.0 gives the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the following code (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nsc.suyog.myotp1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android { lintOptions { abortOnError false }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false

    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
}
```

Also in **gradle-wrapper.properties** add this line or change if already exist with other value:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I have changed this as you stated. Not working, still getting same error. what to do?

Comment: @Suyog try this

Comment: Above both code i have copied and Tried again. Getting same error.

Comment: @Suyog check properties gradle

Comment: I have line: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip Does i have need to update my android studio to 3.3 for gradle-4.10.1-all.zip??

Comment: no, make sure you have internet connection and restart and rebuild your project

Comment: After this Getting new Error called: Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: Tried. No effect :( what are your android studio configs?? is it working with you?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `:15.0.0` from the firebase implementation!

The `implementation` should be like:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

Else every thing seems fine!

Comment: Try using `16.1.0` because there is no release named `16.0.1`

Comment: i have removed the entire line : implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1' still getting same error. change of version is not effecting error.

Comment: There is no connection of installation with this error.

Comment: So I think the error is in this line, add it to the end od the `build.gradle` file: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186842/discussion-between-suyog-and-gourav).